# On click slidetoggle div but not remove css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, removeclass, siblings

I have these divs with slideToggle and I need to change from + to - when they are clicked, but I'm not getting evenly..

I would like that when I clicked on the enclosed div she removed the minus class, but can not in any way

HTML:

```
<div class="equipamentos-div">
<h2 class="equipamentos-title">Luzes</h2>
<div><p>4 Fla shes Style 600 RX (Elinchrom)</p></div>
</div>

<div class="equipamentos-div">
<h2 class="equipamentos-title">Difusores</h2>
<div><p>2 Hazy Light/ Rotalux Softbox 35x90 cm (Elinchrom)</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content .content-equipamentos h2{color:#808080;font-size: 18px;text-transform: none;cursor: pointer;margin: 0;}
#content .content-equipamentos h2:hover{color: #000;}
#content .content-equipamentos h2:after{content:' +';}
#content .content-equipamentos h2.minus{color:#000;}
#content .content-equipamentos h2.minus:after{content:' -';}
#content .content-equipamentos div div{display: none;}
#content .content-equipamentos p{margin-bottom: 10px !important;}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.equipamentos-title').click(function () {
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp().removeClass('minus');
  $(this).toggleClass('minus'); 
  return false;
});
```

[EXAMPLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/dualdesign/8TBC3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
  $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('minus').next().slideUp();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TBC3/1/)

Here, `$(this).parent().siblings().children()` refers to `<h2>` element. Add you need to remove class from this element. Currently you are removing class from `div` following `<h2>`  that you slide up.

Comment: Was just going to post the same. The reason this works OP is because you were removing the class from the `div` that you slid up... yet the class was added to a different div.